# Given a font file and the look of a glyph, how do I find its unicode code point?

Tags: text, glyphs, unicode

I have a font file (*.ttf) and images where a glyph is displayed. What's the easiest way to figure out what code point I should reference to get the correct glyph?

The concrete example is a chevron right, but neither `0xf054` (chevron right in Font Awesome) nor `0xf105` (angle right in FA) match what I need. (The font in question is commercially licensed, so I can't post it here.) Is there a way to programmatically look through the font file to see what code points have defined characters, and what they look like?

I'm on Windows 8.1, so any tools I need must be compatible with that.

Answer (score 6):

All versions of Windows come with the Character Map utility with which you can browse the available glyphs of any installed font. Enabling Advanced View will allow you to filter your results by Character Set or Group; a search function is available as well. This is hardly what I would consider "programatically", but you'll still be able to search for a glyph by appearance.

[image: Windows Character Map]

Some design programs have similar utilities like this baked right into the application. For instance, Adobe Illustrator has a Glyphs pane, though the filtering tools are not as powerful as Windows' Character Map. This can be opened via <kbd>Window > Type > Glyphs</kbd>

[image: Illustrator Glyph pane]